# Proof that $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n\choose k} =2^n$ using Binomial Expansion Formula

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

HW problem here. Not sure how to even start on it.

Prove that $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n\choose k} =2^n$$

Any help is appreciated.

For Search purposes:

(Hint: Use the binomial expansion mentioned on p. 87.)
An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and It's Applications 2.6.58

Comment: What is mentioned on p87?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** it should be mentioned, on p. 87, that
$$\forall x,y\ \ 
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^ky^{n-k} = (x+y)^n,
$$

Comment: oh, and why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote. For future students, consider that the given problem can be written essentially the same way as the above, only with x and y replaced with 1's. Combine that with Sami's answer and you have the proof.

Answer (score 3):

**Second hint**

Use the binomial expansion in
$$(1+1)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to use the binomial theorem, the other answers will do, but a nice way to see this is to count the number of subsets of a set containing $n$ elements. To count this, we can run through each element and choose to include or exclude it from the subset. This is two choices for each element, giving $2^n$ subsets. But we can also count this by adding up the number of subsets of size $k$ for each $k$ ranging from $0$ to $n$; this is $\sum {n \choose k}$.